# What does the notation $[m]=\{1, \ldots, m\}$ mean in the equation of the empirical error?

Tags: machine-learning, computational-learning-theory, notation, books

The empirical error equation given in the book [Understanding Machine Learning: From Theory to Algorithms](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~shais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/understanding-machine-learning-theory-algorithms.pdf) is

[image]

My intuition for this equation is: total wrong predictions divided by the total number of samples $m$ in the given sample set $S$ (Correct me if I'm wrong). But, in this equation, the $m$ takes $\{ 1, \dots, m \}$. How is this actually calculated, as I thought it should be one number (the size of the sample)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a commonly used notation in theoretical computer science.

$[m]$ is *not* the variable $m$, but is instead the set of integers from $1$ to $m$ inclusive. The empirical error equation thus reads in English:

The cardinality of a set consisting of the elements $i$ of the set of integers $[m]$ such that the hypothesis given input $x_i$ disagrees with label $y_i$, normalized by $m$.